# Extract data from XML using Python using Namespace

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, lxml

I am trying to read a SOAP request XML from logs and do some validation by extracting the data but with no success.

Here is the XML i am trying to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <createOrder xmlns="http://services.xxx.xxx.xxx.com">
   <createOrderRequest>
    <ns1:order xmlns:ns1="http://beans.xxx.xxx.xxx.com/xsd">
     <ns1:customer>
      <ns1:billingAddress>
       <ns1:addressLine1>my home address</ns1:addressLine1>
       <ns1:addressLine2></ns1:addressLine2>
       <ns1:addressType>B</ns1:addressType>
       <ns1:city>cityofmine</ns1:city>
       <ns1:countryCode>countrycode</ns1:countryCode>
       <ns1:firstName>Jo</ns1:firstName>
       <ns1:lastName>Sm</ns1:lastName>
        <ns1:state>IL</ns1:state>
       <ns1:zipCode>60135</ns1:zipCode>
      </ns1:billingAddress>
      <ns1:customerReferenceId>xxx@exxx.com</ns1:customerReferenceId>
     </ns1:customer>
     <ns1:items>
      <ns1:addressKey>99999</ns1:addressKey>
      <ns1:orderItemId>xxxxx1231</ns1:orderItemId>
     </ns1:items>
    </ns1:order>
    </createOrderRequest>
  </createOrder>
  </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the code I was trying with but I am not able to find the elements.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def read_create_order():
    tree = ET.parse('create_ord.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    print(root.tag)
    name_space = {'ns1':'http://beans.xxx.xxx.xxx.com/xsd'}
    for item in tree.findall('items', namespaces=name_space):
        print(item)
    for item in root.findall('items', namespaces=name_space):
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this worked for me.But if there are any better solutions where I would like to access the tag by name so that I don't have to loop

```
    ns = etree.FunctionNamespace('http://beans.xxx.xxx.xxx.com/xsd')
    ns.prefix = "ns1"
    ldoc = etree.parse('create_ord.xml')
    for sub_elements in ldoc.xpath('.//ns1:order/ns1:customer/ns1:billingAddress'):
    for element in sub_elements:
        print(element.text)
```

Comment: *"I would like to access the tag by name so that I don't have to loop"*, What specific tag are you trying to access?

Comment: @mzjn I am able to access specific field this way right now `ldoc.xpath('.//ns1:order/ns1:customer')`. But I exactly meant was..in the example code above  `for sub_elements in ldoc.xpath('.//ns1:order/ns1:customer/ns1:billingAddress'):`  once i am in the parent of  `billingAddress` , i want to know if i can do something like `.get('ns1addressLine2') `